# HtmlAgilityPack and attribute-minimization

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

do you know how htmlagilitypack deals with attribute minimization. E.g.:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

controls is minimized and in correct xhmtl this should be written:

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

What node-type would controls be(in the upper example ofc)?

Comment: Load it up in the HAP and save it. I expect it to be an `HtmlAttribute`.

Comment: Already did it. I think its interpreted as an HtmlElement

Comment: What does it save as? The example you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

From the above screenshot, you can see that the type of the "controls" attribute is "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute" and its value is the empty string.